# How does one get a scalar for printing in Racket

Tags: sql, oracle, racket

My program is doing a select like this:

```
(define latest-withdrawal-date
(for/list ([(date-wdrl) 
(in-query odc "select max(student_withdrawal_date) from student_enrollement
where student_id = ? " my_student_id))))
```

Instead of getting back a date though, I get back `#<procedure:date-wdrl>`.

So how can I get the date to display rather than being obscured?

Comment: This code is syntactically incorrect, so it's difficult to diagnose what could be the problem. It appears as if your query is returning a procedure as a representation of a datetime object. Try the util package to convert to srfi/19's datetime for printing. http://docs.racket-lang.org/db/util.html

Comment: I am able to collect date fields in other queries where there would be a number of rows returned. The parents at the end are wrong only because I don't know how to keep them aligned in wiki markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `query-value` to get a scalar result.

From the documentation:

```
(query-value connection stmt arg ...) → any/c 
Executes a SQL query, which must produce exactly one row 
of exactly one column, and returns its single value result.

Examples:
> (query-value pgc "select timestamp 'epoch'")
(sql-timestamp 1970 1 1 0 0 0 0 #f)
> (query-value pgc "select d from the_numbers where n = $1" 3)
"a crowd"
```